# Window shifts with Python Turtle setworldcoordinates()

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I've noticed a strange blip with Python Turtle Graphics when using `Screen.setworldcoordinates()`. For some reason when I click on the window title bar after running the code below, there is a small but perceptible shift of the contents of the window. Can anyone please explain this phenomenon, and let me know if there is way to avoid it? I'm on Windows 10 with Python 3.8.

```
import turtle

screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.setup(500, 500)  # Set the dimensions of the Turtle Graphics window.
screen.setworldcoordinates(0, screen.window_height(), screen.window_width(), 0)

my_turtle = turtle.Turtle(shape="circle")
my_turtle.color("red")
my_turtle.forward(10)

turtle.done()
```

Comment: This does not occur on my system, macOS Mojave, so may be operating system dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turtle comes with it's own [default config](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#how-to-configure-screen-and-turtles), that uses 50% of your monitor width, and 75% of it's height.

```
_CFG = {"width" : 0.5,               # Screen
        "height" : 0.75,
        "canvwidth" : 400,
        "canvheight": 300,
        ...
       }
```

There's some interplay between various elements during construction.

```
self._canvas = TK.Canvas(master, width=width, height=height,
                         bg=self.bg, relief=TK.SUNKEN, borderwidth=2)
```

Setting `borderwidth` to any value above 3 alleviates it;  believe that's because it calls for a complete screen redraw.
`/usr/lib/python3.9/turtle.py` is read-only, though.

Made a local copy with write privs, then modded it for debugging purposes.  Named [turtel.py](https://github.com/doyousketch2/turtel.py) instead, just to keep changes seperate.  Put in a few `print()` statements to figure out when functions were running.

---

**Method 1:**

You can fix it by forcing new values, before screen construction.
Either by supplying your own `turtle.cfg` in the same directory as your script, or

---

**Method 2:**

overriding those values:

```
import turtle
Width, Height = 500, 500
turtle._CFG['canvwidth'], turtle._CFG['canvheight'] = Width, Height
screen = turtle.Screen()
```

---

**Method 3:**

`_setscrollregion(self, srx1, sry1, srx2, sry2)` calls `_rescale(self, xscalefactor, yscalefactor)`
but doesn't call `adjustScrolls(self)` until `onResize(self, event)` is called, after you drag the titlebar.

So you can force a redraw after `screen.setworldcoordinates(0, Height, Width, 0)`

```
cv = screen.getcanvas()
cv.adjustScrolls()
```

---

Uncomment `##`   to enable lines, and try.

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
import turtle

##  print( turtle._CFG['width'], turtle._CFG['height'] )  ##  0.5 0.75
##  print( turtle._CFG['canvwidth'], turtle._CFG['canvheight'] )  ##  400 300

Width, Height = 500, 500

##  turtle._CFG['width'], turtle._CFG['height'] = Width, Height
##  turtle._CFG['canvwidth'], turtle._CFG['canvheight'] = Width, Height

screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.setworldcoordinates(0, Height, Width, 0)

##  cv = screen.getcanvas()
##  cv.adjustScrolls()

my_turtle = turtle.Turtle(shape='circle')
my_turtle.color('red')
my_turtle.forward(10)

def click_callback( x, y ):
    cv = screen.getcanvas()
    print( cv.width, cv.height, screen.screensize(), cv.winfo_width(), cv.winfo_height() )

print('<<  initialized  >>')
screen.onclick( click_callback )
screen.mainloop()
```